# Why is HTML5 Canvas blurry?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that is supposed to fill 100% of its parent div and scale height based on a ratio. The image that is placed in it is supposed to fill the canvas's height while scaling its width so it doesn't get distorted. That seems to be working but everything on the canvas is really blurry. Why is this happening and how might I display crisp images, shapes and text?

[image]

```js
const photo = 'https://docplayer.net/docs-images/54/10835314/images/page_1.jpg';
const canvasRef = document.getElementById('canvas');
const mugRatioWidth = 2681;
const mugRatioHeight = 1110;
const canvasRatio = mugRatioHeight / mugRatioWidth;
const img = new Image();
const ctx = canvasRef.getContext("2d");
canvasRef.style.width = '100%';

img.src = photo;
img.onload = () => {
       const hRatio = canvasRef.width  / img.width  ;
       const vRatio =  canvasRef.height / img.height  ;
       const ratio  = Math.min ( hRatio, vRatio );
       const centerShift_x = ( canvasRef.width - img.width*ratio ) / 2;
       const centerShift_y = ( canvasRef.height - img.height*ratio ) / 2;
       ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasRef.width, canvasRef.height);
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width, img.height, centerShift_x,centerShift_y,img.width*ratio, img.height*ratio);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillText("Text example!", 10, 90);
 }
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'/>
```

Comment: Could you maybe post a picture of the original image and of the canvas? It's hard to diagnose "blurry" without seeing it.

Comment: Sure, that's updated now

Comment: You need to set the canvas resolution to match the image. eg in onload set canvas res with `canvasRef.width = img.naturalWidth; canvasRef.height = img.naturalHeight;`

Comment: to add to Blindman67's comment, the reason it becomes blurry is because you changed the CSS style width and/or height. When you apply CSS to canvas to change the size, it stretches the canvas. The canvas needs to have height/width set directly, not with CSS.

Comment: I'm gonna add even more: you should set height and width to define the "resolution" of your canvas, and then size it in CSS to fit it in your documents. The 2 aren't incompatible, they just serve different purposes.

Comment: @Sheraff no that will cause issues if the CSS causes it to become larger, or if it changes the aspect ratio. CSS is only compatible if you preserve the aspect ratio and keep it the same size or smaller.

Comment: @Chris Rollins Yeah exactly. In CSS you should treat the canvas as you would an image.